# How can I reduce and control bird dander?

Tags: birds, cleaning, allergies

My wife just found out she has a condition which is worsened by many types of allergens, like bird dander.  We have 5 parakeets, 1 pineapple green cheek conure, and a cockatiel.

The cockatiel produces the greatest amount of dander when he shakes out, but we've had him for 10 years and he's around 15 years and thus my wife doesn't want to re-home him.

**What can I do to reduce the amount of bird dander?**

I'm considering an air purification unit, but I've heard from a news report that many are not as effective as they say they are. I'm interested in knowing what people's experience is with air purification units used around birds.  Is there anything else I can do to control the amount of bird dander?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What can I do to reduce the amount of bird dander?

Make sure that your bird is able to bathe himself. Aside from that, the rest comes down to cleaning, like changing newspaper/cage liners, sweeping, vaccuming, etc. Since your wife is the one allergic, it is best if she does not clean the cage at all, or if she does, to wear a face mask. Reducing the number of birds can help, and moving the cage to a place where there is not carpet (say, tile instead) helps a lot.

> My wife just found out she has a condition which is worsened by many types of allergens, like bird dander.

As you pointed out, bird dander is only one part of the equation.

- Air purification units can help, but certain units work better than others - and they only work well if their filters are cleaned.
- Replace the air filter in your home (where the Air Conditioning comes in/out) on schedule, and use the highest quality pads. There is a rating that is acceptable for removing allergens.
- Replace/clean the air filter in your vacuum on schedule, and/or consider a vacuum that has high-grade filters, like HEPA.
- If mold is a trigger, you'll want to get rid of any indoor plants, as they are high producers of it.
- Depending on allergens, you may wish to look into special bedding. There are beddings available now that have initial scientific results pointing to better health for asthmatic patients.
- There are many other tips, but I wanted to cover the ones that have the highest impact